# Intellij Android Gradle Plugin Unsupported method: Dependencies.getJars()

Tags: intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I am having issues with my Intellij set up. I am able to build successfully from the command line, but when I try to refresh my build file it never completes and just says 'Gradle project sync in progress...'. When I tail the logs, I get this:

```
INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [--init-script, /private/var/folders/nj/qb8hxhjx6ng8bp5c0070dt3m0000gn/T/ijinit9082569265104558481.gradle]
INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 2 ms
INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to update
INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 0 ms
ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - null
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:132)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeAndWaitIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeOnEdt(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:377)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeProjectChangeAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:359)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$MyMultiExternalProjectRefreshCallback.onSuccess(ExternalSystemUtil.java:760)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1126)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1103)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1326)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeAndWaitIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2074)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.model.UnsupportedMethodException: Unsupported method: Dependencies.getJars().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
    at org.gradle.tooling.model.internal.Exceptions.unsupportedMethod(Exceptions.java:33)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.getJars(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dependency.Dependency.populate(Dependency.java:99)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dependency.Dependency.extractFrom(Dependency.java:88)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.DependenciesModuleCustomizer.setUpDependencies(DependenciesModuleCustomizer.java:50)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.DependenciesModuleCustomizer.setUpDependencies(DependenciesModuleCustomizer.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.AbstractDependenciesModuleCustomizer.customizeModule(AbstractDependenciesModuleCustomizer.java:57)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.customizeModule(AndroidProjectDataService.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.access$100(AndroidProjectDataService.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService$1.execute(AndroidProjectDataService.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.DisposeAwareProjectChange.run(DisposeAwareProjectChange.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$5$1.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:364)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:984)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:361)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeOnEdt(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:374)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeProjectChangeAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:359)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.importData(AndroidProjectDataService.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:90)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$MyMultiExternalProjectRefreshCallback$1$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:766)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.mergeRootsChangesDuring(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:329)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$MyMultiExternalProjectRefreshCallback$1.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:763)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.DisposeAwareProjectChange.run(DisposeAwareProjectChange.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$5$1.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:364)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:984)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:361)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4  Build #IU-135.1230
ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.6.0_65
ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: Apple Inc.
ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Mac OS X
ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action: ExternalSystem.RefreshAllProjects
```

Anyone have any ideas, I can't seem to figure out the source of either of the errors I am seeing.

Comment: Considering that the stack says, "The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method", I'd start *there* and see what you could do to upgrade your version of Gradle.

Comment: I am using a gradle wrapper. And I have told Intellij to use it, if it works from the command line then why would it not work from Intellij?

Comment: Be sure that IntelliJ is using the same wrapper that you are.

Comment: I have checked 'Use default gradle wrapper'. Which I believe means it will use the version of gradle I specify in my gradle-wrapper-properties file.

Comment: What version of Android Studio, what version of Gradle, and what version of the Android-Gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using `IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4  Build #IU-135.1230`, and `0.13` for my Android-Gradle plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use v0.13 of the Android Gradle plugin at the time of this writing, you should use Android Studio 0.8.11 or later. While IntelliJ has the Android plugin built-in, it doesn't update as often and isn't the latest version, and support for 0.13 of the Gradle plugin was added very recently.